# How to dynamically change/set arrow size of an edge in sigma v2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sigma.js

I am trying to let the user control the arrow size without affecting the size of the edge, in v1 (canvas renderer), it was done like with changing the `minArrowSize` in the settings, this is not the case in v2 (WebGL).

I have seen this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73988100/9294601 that allows me to statically modify the size of the input, but how can I access this `thickness` variable dyanmically

I tried this but as expected, it did not work (note: I am using sim51/react-sigma

```
<SigmaContainer
                        settings={{
                            nodeProgramClasses: {image: getNodeProgramImage(), circle: CircleNodeProgram},
                            edgeProgramClasses: {
                                arrow: ArrowEdgeProgram,
                            },
                            minArrowSize: 100,
                            ...graphSettings,
                        }}
                        style={{height: '100%', background: props.noBackground ? 'white' : mainBackgroundColor}}
                    >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I utilized the solution I posted in my question with a slight twist, in the custom arrowhead, you'll find `data` attribute passed to process, this represent the edge, what you can do is pass another attribute, called for example minArrowSize (or whatever other name you want), and modify the thickness like this:

`const thickness = data.minArrowSize || 1;`

so the complete arrowProgram would be

```
import {AbstractEdgeProgram} from 'sigma/rendering/webgl/programs/common/edge';
import fragmentShaderSource from 'sigma/rendering/webgl/shaders/edge.arrowHead.frag.glsl';
import vertexShaderSource from 'sigma/rendering/webgl/shaders/edge.arrowHead.vert.glsl';
import {floatColor} from 'sigma/utils';

const POINTS = 3;
const ATTRIBUTES = 9;
const STRIDE = POINTS * ATTRIBUTES;

export default class EdgeArrowHeadProgram extends AbstractEdgeProgram {

    constructor(gl) {
        super(gl, vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource, POINTS, ATTRIBUTES);

        // Locations
        this.positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_position');
        this.colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_color');
        this.normalLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_normal');
        this.radiusLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_radius');
        this.barycentricLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_barycentric');

        // Uniform locations
        const matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'u_matrix');
        if (matrixLocation === null) throw new Error('EdgeArrowHeadProgram: error while getting matrixLocation');
        this.matrixLocation = matrixLocation;

        const sqrtZoomRatioLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'u_sqrtZoomRatio');

        if (sqrtZoomRatioLocation === null) {
            throw new Error('EdgeArrowHeadProgram: error while getting sqrtZoomRatioLocation');
        }

        this.sqrtZoomRatioLocation = sqrtZoomRatioLocation;

        const correctionRatioLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'u_correctionRatio');

        if (correctionRatioLocation === null) {
            throw new Error('EdgeArrowHeadProgram: error while getting correctionRatioLocation');
        }

        this.correctionRatioLocation = correctionRatioLocation;

        this.bind();
    }

    // Locations
    positionLocation;

    colorLocation;

    normalLocation;

    radiusLocation;

    barycentricLocation;

    matrixLocation;

    sqrtZoomRatioLocation;

    correctionRatioLocation;

    bind() {
        const gl = this.gl;

        // Bindings
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.positionLocation);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.normalLocation);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.radiusLocation);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.colorLocation);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.barycentricLocation);

        gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, ATTRIBUTES * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.normalLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, ATTRIBUTES * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 8);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.radiusLocation, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, ATTRIBUTES * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 16);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            this.colorLocation,
            4,
            gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            true,
            ATTRIBUTES * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
            20,
        );

        // TODO: maybe we can optimize here by packing this in a bit mask
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            this.barycentricLocation,
            3,
            gl.FLOAT,
            false,
            ATTRIBUTES * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
            24,
        );
    }

    computeIndices() {
    // nothing to do
    }

    process(
        sourceData,
        targetData,
        data,
        hidden,
        offset,
    ) {
        if (hidden) {
            for (let i = offset * STRIDE, l = i + STRIDE; i < l; i++) this.array[i] = 0;

            return;
        }

        const thickness = data.minArrowSize || 1;
        const radius = targetData.size || 1;
        const x1 = sourceData.x;
        const y1 = sourceData.y;
        const x2 = targetData.x;
        const y2 = targetData.y;
        const color = floatColor(data.color);

        // Computing normals
        const dx = x2 - x1;
        const dy = y2 - y1;

        let len = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        let n1 = 0;
        let n2 = 0;

        if (len) {
            len = 1 / Math.sqrt(len);

            n1 = -dy * len * thickness;
            n2 = dx * len * thickness;
        }

        let i = POINTS * ATTRIBUTES * offset;

        const array = this.array;

        // First point
        array[i++] = x2;
        array[i++] = y2;
        array[i++] = -n1;
        array[i++] = -n2;
        array[i++] = radius;
        array[i++] = color;
        array[i++] = 1;
        array[i++] = 0;
        array[i++] = 0;

        // Second point
        array[i++] = x2;
        array[i++] = y2;
        array[i++] = -n1;
        array[i++] = -n2;
        array[i++] = radius;
        array[i++] = color;
        array[i++] = 0;
        array[i++] = 1;
        array[i++] = 0;

        // Third point
        array[i++] = x2;
        array[i++] = y2;
        array[i++] = -n1;
        array[i++] = -n2;
        array[i++] = radius;
        array[i++] = color;
        array[i++] = 0;
        array[i++] = 0;
        array[i] = 1;
    }

    render(params) {
        if (this.hasNothingToRender()) return;

        const gl = this.gl;

        const program = this.program;
        gl.useProgram(program);

        // Binding uniforms
        gl.uniformMatrix3fv(this.matrixLocation, false, params.matrix);
        gl.uniform1f(this.sqrtZoomRatioLocation, Math.sqrt(params.ratio));
        gl.uniform1f(this.correctionRatioLocation, params.correctionRatio);

        // Drawing:
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.array.length / ATTRIBUTES);
    }

}
```

and you would just modify this arrow size in your regular code:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const {minArrowSize} = graphSettings;
        graph.updateEachEdgeAttributes((edgeId, e)=>{
            const updatedEdge = {
                ...e,
                minArrowSize,
            };

            return updatedEdge;
        });
    }, [graphSettings.minArrowSize]);
```

also don't forget to do a hard refresh after that so that changes in the arrowProgram file reflect